# Reactjs/Next.js avoid function repetitions

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, next.js

I'm working with Next.js/React and inside a `getServerSideProps()` i'm fetching mongodb data to pass as *props* to the page, therefore to my *component*

To fetch this data I'm using some functions, which repeat the same except for the name of the collection, and since the database has been built using some _Join collection to pair stuff, i'm making two queries each fetch.

Is there a way to avoid repeating such functions? I'm not sure if I should streamline the js itself by avoiding the functions to repeat multiple times or to improve the mongodb query so that it becomes one maybe?

The code (inside `getServerSideProps`) looks like:

```
//...etc

// # FUNCTION 20
// ...

// # FUNCTION 21
var acce = null
const midAcce = await db.collection('_Join:users:Accessories').find({ relatedId: userId }).toArray()
if (midAcce.length) {
  acce = []
  for (let r=0; r < midAcce.length; r++) { 
    const foundAcce = await db.collection('Accessories').find({ _id: midAcce[r].owningId }).toArray()
    if (foundAcce[0].image[0].src){
      let acceObj = {
        name: foundAcce[0].name,
        image: foundAcce[0].image[0].src
      }
      acce.push(acceObj)
    }
  }
}

// # FUNCTION 22
var equip = null
const midEquip = await db.collection('_Join:users:Equipments').find({ relatedId: userId }).toArray()
if (midEquip.length) {
  equip = []
  for (let r=0; r < midEquip.length; r++) { 
    const foundEquip = await db.collection('Equipments').find({ _id: midEquip[r].owningId }).toArray()
    if (foundEquip[0].image[0].src){
      let equipObj = {
        name: foundEquip[0].name,
        image: foundEquip[0].image[0].src
      }
      equip.push(equipObj)
    }
  }
}

// position for google maps ("foundUser" is retrieved earlier on, don't mind about this pos)
var pos = null
if (foundUser[0].cont.addr){
  pos = foundUser[0].cont.addr
}else if (foundUser[0].loc){
  pos = foundUser[0].loc
}

// finally create object to pass as props to the page then to component
forcomponent = {
  // ... many more as the two below
  acce: acce,
  equip: equip,
  pos: pos
}
```

Comment: To answer your design question, think about the next person to work on your code. Will it help that person understand and maintain the code if you create an api that accepts a parameter to tell it whether to handle `Equipments` or `Accessories`? Will it help the person who might refactor your database? Or will it just raise a barrier to understanding your code for the maintainer?

Comment: That's also to consider for sure! So is leaving multiple functions/calls to the db like this good practice (or normal at least)?

Comment: I would say mainting 20x examples of this code that just vaguely varies in variable naming is a problem in itself.

Comment: I think I'm going to do a forLoop with two arrays for the collection names to start with.. do you know if there's a more perfmormant way to do such mongodb query?

Comment: @max, agreed. If their are multiple methods almost the same, definitely parameterize them and unify them.. But be  sure to write some comments (JSDoc comments, maybe) explaining how to use the unified methods. Take seriously the impact on the next guy of building an abstraction, and explain it.